# How do I set_weights and train them later?

Tags: python, keras

I have some special processes to define the weights from my neurons on a Neural network, so I need to use `layer.set_weights()` to prepare them.

After it I try directly to run `model.evaluate()` and it works. Then I try to train it with

```
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=5, verbose = 1)
```

But it starts with a Accuracy and maintains it, it doesn't change during the training, the layers are all `Trainable:True`.

That's the output of my `fit` with 5 Epochs, but it's the same with 500:

```
Epoch 1/5
460/460 [==============================] - 0s 54us/step - loss: 1.1919 - acc: 0.6196
Epoch 2/5
460/460 [==============================] - 0s 44us/step - loss: 1.1919 - acc: 0.6196
Epoch 3/5
460/460 [==============================] - 0s 43us/step - loss: 1.1919 - acc: 0.6196
Epoch 4/5
460/460 [==============================] - 0s 41us/step - loss: 1.1919 - acc: 0.6196
Epoch 5/5
460/460 [==============================] - 0s 34us/step - loss: 1.1918 - acc: 0.6196
```

So my question is, if I use `set_weights()` before calling `fit()`, does Keras simply ignore them? I want them to not be ignored, I want them to adapt during the training. How should I proceed?

Here is how I'm defining my layers:

```
#this is the input tensor
inputs = Input(shape=(inputSize,), name='input')

#this is the Neurule layer (Layer 1)
x = Dense(neurulesQt, activation='sigmoid', name='neurules')(inputs)

# Layer 2 - with ORs
x = Dense(5, activation='sigmoid', name='layer2-ORs')(x)
# Layer 3 - with 2 ORs and 1 Buffer
y = Dense(2, activation='softmax', name='layer3-ORs_andOutput')(x)
```

And then setting the weights loaded from a JSON:

```
layer1 = model.layers[1]
layer2 = model.layers[2]
layer3 = model.layers[3]

layer1.set_weights(weightsAndBias1)
layer2.set_weights(weightsAndBias2)
layer3.set_weights(weightsAndBias3)
```

**EDIT:** I've tried with a lot more epochs, and it starts to change after more or less 600 epochs, but out of nothing, it is flat until there. How should I change my optimizer to accelerate this process?

Comment: You can try to use at first an `'adam'` optimizer and a `'categorical_crossentropy'` loss. --- There might be simmetry problems if your weights are exact values and your model might be in the middle of a simmetry region, you could try to add a little random noise in your weights, maibe.

Comment: Have you tried decreasing (or increasing) the learning rate of optimizer?

Comment: @today I've tried from 1e-4 until 1e-20, wasn't much better, but with 0.1 it stays flat for "only" 90 epochs or so.

Comment: @DanielMöller wow, with Adam it is much better! Thanks